# Can I become a pilot if I have a medical/dental problem?

Tags: pilots

Can I become a pilot if I have a dental problem (I don't have 6teeth I have artificial one)  and I broke my chin bone I have a steel plate there and I really want to become a pilot is this okay? can I still become pilot as I don't have any other defect in my body ?

Comment: What country are you in?  The regulations may vary depending on your location.

Answer (score 1):

Under FAA regulations (which most people in the world can train under if they come to the USA) you should be fine. There are no dental requirements to be a pilot or obtain a medical certificate (as far as I know). You can [reach out an AME in your local area](https://designee.faa.gov/SelectTypeOfSearch/SelectTypeOfSearch) if you are concerned, they should be able to answer the question for you. [The only orally related regulations are that you be able to speak english proficiently and clearly.](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_60-28B.pdf) As long as you can do so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link for the FAA i.e the US one:
https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/standards/
, Europe has other standards, I am not a AME ( Aeronautical Medical examiner) but I would think it poses no problems to have dental issues for an initial, in Europe we needed to have a certain mastication coefficient that is you can chew food properly that’s all as far as i remember.